# Get the UserID for an IAM user programatically using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to get the UserId after the creation of user, suing "account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('some_other_user')", but for output I get none, what could be the reason. I am very new to boto and python so it might be something very small.

```
import boto3
import sys
import json
iam = boto3.resource('iam') #resource representing IAM
group = iam.Group('group1') # Name of group
created_user = iam.create_user(
    UserName='some_other_user'
)
account_id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('some_other_user')
print(account_id)    
create_group_response = iam.create_group(GroupName = 'group1')
response = group.add_user(
UserName='some_other_user' #name of user
)
group = iam.Group('group1')
response = group.attach_policy(
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::196687784:policy/boto-test'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [get_caller_identity()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity) function returns a dict containing:

```
{
    'UserId': 'AIDAEXAMPLEHERE',
    'Account': '123456789012',
    'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/james'
}
```

So, to use this:

```
import boto3
sts = boto3.client('sts')
response = sts.get_caller_identity()
print('User ID:', response['UserId'])
```

Or you can use `response.get('UserId')` to get the user ID. The key to the user ID in the response dictionary is always the literal `UserId`. It doesn't vary (you cannot call `response.get('james')`, for example).

You cannot retrieve the identity of an arbitrary IAM principal using `sts.get_caller_identity()`. It only gives you the identity associated with the credentials that you implicitly used when making the call.